# What do the "Fetch Wallet" options when opening a Ripple wallet mean?

Tags: ripple

When I open a Ripple account, I can choose to fetch my wallet from

- Payward, Local Browser
- Payward
- Local Browser

What does this mean? Can someone elaborate on the differences, and when is each option appropriate?

Comment: Are there still 2 people voting to close ripple questions, despite being consensus on meta that they are in-topic? How childish they are?

Comment: @Lohoris - not just voting to close, but without identifying themselves...

Comment: we could vote to close too, to reveal them.

Comment: @Lohoris - nah, no point.

Comment: I voted to close on this and all other Ripple questions I see.  I feel the Ripple questions detract from this SE and will continue to use my "vote" in this manner.

Comment: @StephenGornick - why don't you come talk about it here? http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/335/should-this-se-also-cover-questions-about-ripple

Comment: @StephenGornick - wait ... you have. Is this reply ironic? http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/345/78 I took it as a vote from you for including Ripple on Bitcoin SE?

Comment: @StephenGornick this is abusing the system: once it has been established that community thinks it is in-topic, you no longer have the right to vote to close.

Comment: @Lohoris - of course he has the right to vote to close, it's just childish and futile to insist on doing this if the vast majority will disregard it.

Comment: @ripper234 no, you have to provide a reason to close a question, and if the reason is "it's OT" when the FAQ says it is IT, he's abusing the system.

Comment: If others join me and Ripple questions continuously get closed then maybe the topic of what the community wants here gets revisited.   Incidentally, I want Ripple to succeed.  I just want the Bitcoin SE to remain the Bitcoin SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- "Payward, Local Browser" tries to fetch your wallet from Payward and if an account has not been found or if the Payward is not available / you are offline, it tries to fetch the wallet from local storage.
- "Payward" only looks in Payward.
- "Local" only looks in local storage.

P. S. You've set where to save your wallet in https://ripple.com/client/#/register right after the "Create Wallet" button.

Comment: What's a payward? And why must this post be 30 long?

Comment: You can store your encrypted wallet in Payward server, and access it everywhere, not only from your local machine.