# What are the ways to create an offline Ripple wallet?

Tags: ripple

Do I have to download/compile my own version of the client? Is there a difference between the Ripple and Bitcoin wallet address creation methods, or can I use, say brainwallet, also for Ripple?

Note: even if it is not correct, I use terms wallet and address interchangeably. I assume that wallet is just a (possibly encrypted) container of addresses and corresponding public/private keys.

Comment: Actually a ripple wallet, unless I'm mistaken, contains only one address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of one of http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7849/what-do-the-fetch-wallet-options-when-opening-a-ripple-wallet-mean or http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9002/how-do-i-backup-my-ripple-wallet or http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9783/how-exactly-is-my-account-wallet-at-ripple-com-secure

Comment: None of the links answer the exact question: how can I *create* (not copy and download from the site that gave it to me) my own secure wallet. Offline means that I don't want to be connected to Internet while creating a wallet - say like using brain wallet JavaScript offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two components of making a Ripple wallet offline:

1. [The blob vault](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/Blob-Vault)
   This is what stores the private key that controls your wallet. Other people can try to guess your username/password over the network, and if the blob vault isn't trustworthy, then it can do a much faster attack against it.
   Install instructions: There is an install script included (`serversetup.sh`), but it will only work on Debian-based systems. You can get it to work on others by installing node, npm, and mysql server. Be aware that you also need to edit the script and replace `PASSWORD` with your actual mysql root password.
2. [The ripple client itself](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/blob/master/index.html)
   Copy it to a [local webserver](http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-and-configure-apache-in-ubuntu/2011/03/09), and point your brower at it.

Be aware that you need to be online to see the balance of your Ripple wallet.

Comment: I am getting a more complete picture now, but I really need this and all three links (possible duplicate above) for it. Ripple address is public key and secret is private key. Blob vault entry contains wallet name, passphrase, public key, timestamp and IP. Private key is somehow generated from name and passphrase, but, since vault mustn't be able to do the same, it is either unique even for identical name and passphrase, or vault's copy of name and passphrase are already encrypted with private key. If wallet contains private key, then one may not want it stored remotely.

Comment: @Bitripple `I really need this and all three links (possible duplicate above) for it. ` I don't understand what that means. `Private key is somehow generated from name and passphrase, but, since vault mustn't be able to do the same` Actually, if the vault knows your password and username, they can absolutely steal your money. `wallet contains private key, may not want it stored remotely.` You might not. I agree.

Comment: `I really need this and all three links` means that only by reading the source code and all 3 answers I managed to understand how this works well enough. I am now trying to use brainwallet to see if I can generate my private and public keys from wallet name and passphrase.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, since there is no answer for days already, I think this link contains probably the closest to one:

[Description of credentials Blob Vault](https://ripple.com/credentials/)

One can set up his own Blob Vault or use a public one. Where is the source code for it, I don't know yet. Also not sure of exact relationship with Ripple address.

Comment: https://github.com/rippleFoundation/Blob-Vault You're correct that most of ripple isn't open-source though.

Comment: Why didn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: As of September 25, 2013, all of [Ripple is open source](https://ripple.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3718&p=18013#p18013).