# How exactly is my account/wallet at ripple.com secure?

Tags: security, ripple

Ok, I have my wallet name, passphrase and secret account key issued by 'the network'.
Now say that ripple.com is under DDOS attack or, for whatever reason closes for a month or even becomes inaccessible for even longer periods.

What exactly is the procedure that I need to follow to re-establish my wallet elsewhere? How do I find those @elsewhere that I may go to, if ripple.com is down? How do those at elsewhere know that my wallet passphrase and secret key is for real, if say ripple.com hrad drives all burnt in accidental fire in the building and they have no more records of my wallet?

Ok, so some distributed database has all the data about my wallet but what makes it itself secure, except maybe the sheer potential redundancy of entries, hopefully including one entry for my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ripple.com only hosts the javascript client which talks to the Ripple network via websockets. Once Ripple is out of beta there will likely be different clients to choose from (smart phone apps; command line clients; desktop apps; etc). The existing javascript client is already open source and you can host it locally if you like (and have the technical know-how). Thus if Ripple.com becomes unreachable you have other client options. These options will only improve as Ripple grows and leaves beta.

Your Ripple wallet contains your secret key and your contacts in an encrypted form. Your balances and configured credit lines are stored in the ledger in the distributed ripple network. Currently there are only a dozen or so ripple servers all under the control of OpenCoin (in order to make it easy for them to make changes during the beta to the server code that would otherwise disrupt the network). As long as there are a sufficient majority of ripple servers intercommunicating you only need to be able to communicate with one of them (bitcoin is vaguely similar in that there is an intercommunicating network or bitcoind processes). Currently the webclient connects to `s1.ripple.com` by default (look under `Advanced->Options`) presumably this could point to any ripple server, and perhaps once out of beta the clients will have a list of servers to try.

When you created your wallet and when you login with the webclient there is a "Fetch Wallet" option (see [What do the "Fetch Wallet" options when opening a Ripple wallet mean?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7849/what-do-the-fetch-wallet-options-when-opening-a-ripple-wallet-mean)) that controls where the wallet is stored. By default an encrypted version is stored "in the cloud" and locally by your browser. With the default options, if you run the webclient from the same machine+browser it can use just the local copy if the cloud storage is unavailable. If you move to a new machine or a different browser, the copy in the cloud needs to be accessible. You can also make a local backup of your wallet to a file, see [How do I backup my Ripple wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9002/how-do-i-backup-my-ripple-wallet)

If for any reason there is no copy of your wallet available, all is not lost. Ripple lets you create a new wallet using your existing secret key (which is why they strongly recommend making a copy of the secret key). Since the wallet only holds your secret key and your contacts, all you will have lost is your contact names. The client would show your trust/credit lines and transaction history using just the ripple addresses of others. You'd just need to re-enter the contact names (perhaps recognizing your contacts by your current trust/credit limits and balances or perhaps needing to ask your contacts again for their addresses).

Comment: Any idea when Ripple be out of beta?